# Issue with linked list program to count and sort in C

Tags: html, c, sorting, linked-list, counting

The problem that is to be solved by this C program is that it should count the number of tags in an HTML file (which is inputted using input redirection) and then display all unique tags along with their counts. There is a restrictive definition of what a tag is considered to be: Assume an HTML tag starts right after '<' and terminates with either a space or '>', also the tag is to be only alphanumeric. For example, `<h1>` and `<span` are HTML tags while `<!--` and `</p>` are not. The program further takes input from the user from the command line. If the user inputs -a, then the tags are to be printed in alphabetic order, if -n then they are printed in descending order according to the count and if there is no input then the tags are just printed in the order they are stored with their counts. Other inputs are similar.

The issue that I am facing with my code is that sometimes, the same tag is printed twice such as span: 1 span: 1 when it should be span: 2 instead of separately printing its occurrences. Other tags get printed fine. I cannot find a specific order for why some tags get printed/counted this way. My other issue is that my program is also printing a peculiar tag of the form p or P(with some sort of symbol) which doesn't look right (see faulty output). My last issue is there is some problem with my method that sorts in descending order as it is not sorting correctly and it also causes a segmentation fault when I try to input different HTML files.

Required Output(No sort):

```
HTML Tags Found:
body: 1
div: 1
p: 2
b: 2
span: 2
```

Faulty Outputs(no sort and sort):

```
$ ./countTags < A1.html
HTML Tags Found:
P/3: 307
body: 1
div: 1
p: 2
b: 2
span: 1
span: 1


$ ./countTags -a < A1.html
HTML Tags Found:
Pz▒▒: 509
b: 2
body: 1
div: 1
p: 2
span: 1
span: 1


$ ./countTags -n < A1.html
HTML Tags Found:
P: 713
```

My Code:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TAG_LEN 10

void insertNode(Node * head_ref, char newData[MAX_TAG_LEN])
{
    Node * new_node = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
 
    // Used in step 5
    Node * last = head_ref; 
  
    // 2. Put in the data 
    strcpy(new_node->data, newData); //new_node->data  = newData;
    new_node->count = 1;
 
    // 3. This new node is going to be the
    //    last node, so make next of it as NULL
    new_node->next = NULL;
 
    // 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make
    // the new node as head
    if (head_ref == NULL)
    {
       head_ref->next = new_node;
       return;
    } 
      
    // 5. Else traverse till the last node
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;
  
    // 6. Change the next of last node
    last->next = new_node;
    return;   
}

void sortLinkedListAlphabetically(Node** head) {
  Node* sortedList = NULL;
  Node* unsortedList = *head;

  while (unsortedList != NULL) {
    Node* nodeToInsert = unsortedList;
    unsortedList = unsortedList->next;

    // Find the correct position to insert the node in the sorted list
    if (sortedList == NULL || strcmp(nodeToInsert->data, sortedList->data) < 0) {
      // Insert the node at the beginning of the sorted list
      nodeToInsert->next = sortedList;
      sortedList = nodeToInsert;
    } else {
      // Traverse the sorted list to find the correct position to insert the node
      Node* current = sortedList;
      while (current->next != NULL && strcmp(nodeToInsert->data, current->next->data) >= 0) {
        current = current->next;
      }

      // Insert the node before the node at the current position
      nodeToInsert->next = current->next;
      current->next = nodeToInsert;
    }
  }

  // Update the head of the original linked list to point to the head of the sorted list
  *head = sortedList;
}

void sortListDescending(Node** head) {
    Node* current = *head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    Node* next = NULL;
    int swapped = 1;
 
    if (*head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
 
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = 0;
        prev = NULL;
        current = *head;
 
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            if (current->data < current->next->data) {
                next = current->next;
                current->next = next->next;
                next->next = current;
 
                if (prev != NULL) {
                    prev->next = next;
                }
                prev = next;
                swapped = 1;
            }
            else {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printLinkedList(Node* head) {
  Node* current = head;

  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%s: %d\n", current->data, current->count);
    current = current->next;
  }

  printf("\n");
}

void countTags(char input[])
{   
    Node * head = NULL;
    head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    int maxTags = 0;
    int c;
    int within_tag = 0;
    char tagName[MAX_TAG_LEN];
    int tagNameLen = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {   
        if(c == '<')
        {   
            within_tag = 1;
            tagNameLen = 0;
        }
        else if(c == '>' || c == ' ')
        {   
            within_tag = 0;
            tagName[tagNameLen] = '\0';
            
                if(c == '>')
                {   Node *last = head; 
                    int found = 0;
                    //printf("%s ~", tagName);
                    //putchar('\n');
                    while(last->next != NULL)
                    {   //printf("%s *", last->data);
                        //putchar('\n');
                        if(strcmp(last->data, tagName) == 0)
                        {   //printf("%s - %s*",last->data, tagName);
                            //putchar('\n');
                            found = 1;
                            last->count++;
                        }
                        
                        last = last->next;
                    }

                    if(found == 0)
                    {   
                        int k;
                        int alpha1 = 1;
                       
                            //printf("%s -", tagName);
                            //putchar('\n');
                            for(k=0; k<tagNameLen; k++)
                            {   
                                if(isalnum(tagName[k]) == 0)
                                {  
                                    alpha1 = 0;
                                }
                                
                            }
                            if(alpha1 == 1)
                            {   
                                insertNode(head, tagName);
                            }
                        
                    }
                }

        }
        else if(within_tag)
        {  
            if(tagNameLen < MAX_TAG_LEN )
            {   
                tagName[tagNameLen] = c;
                tagNameLen++;
            }
        }
    }
    


    if((strcmp(input, "") == 0))
    {   printf("HTML Tags Found:\n");
        printLinkedList(head);
    }
    else if((strcmp(input, "-a") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "-a-n") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "-n-a") == 0))
    {
        sortLinkedListAlphabetically(&(head->next));
        printf("HTML Tags Found:\n");
        printLinkedList(head);

    }
    else if((strcmp(input, "-n") == 0))
    {  
        sortListDescending(&head);
        printf("HTML Tags Found:\n");
        printLinkedList(head);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    char input1[3], input2[3];

    if(argc == 2)
    {   
        strcpy(input1, argv[1]);
        countTags(input1);
    }
    else if(argc>2)
    {
        strcpy(input1, argv[1]);
        strcpy(input2, argv[2]);
        
        char* input3;
        input3 = malloc(strlen(input1)+1+2); 
        strcpy(input3, input1); 
        strcat(input3, input2);
      
        countTags(input3);                                                                                          
    }
    else
    {
        countTags("");
    }

}
```

Header file for the struct:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#define MAX_TAG_LEN 10

typedef struct listNode
{
    char data[MAX_TAG_LEN];
    int count;
    struct listNode * next;
} Node;

#endif
```

HTML file inputted via input redirection:

```
<body lang=EN-CA link=blue vlink="#954F72">
<div class=WordSection1>
<p class=MsoNormal><b><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:14.0pt;font-family: "Times New Roman",serif'>Sample</span></b></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><b><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:14.0pt;font-family: "Times New Roman",serif'>Problem 0</span></b></p>
```

Comment: This seems to be a good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. with an input you know will fail, use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values to see what happens and where things start to go wrong.

Comment: Also to help with debugging I suggest you start over, with an empty `main` function. Build it with extra warnings enabled, that you treat as errors. When it builds cleanly, test it. When it passes all possible tests, the add a ***small*** piece of code. Build (cleanly) and test. This makes is much more easy to test and debug problems that might occur, and to isolate the problem so you don't have to worry about the rest of the code. Use simple hard-coded dummy data if needed, for your tests.

Comment: And to better visualize lists, use pencil and paper *first*, before you write any code, to perform your operations. Use labeled boxes for the nodes, and arrows for links and other pointers. As you perform operations, erase and redraw the arrows (pointers, links) as needed. Only when you get it to work on paper implement it in code. I also recommend you use this technique to visualize the lists while debugging your code, draw, erase and redraw on paper as you perform the operations in code, and if there's a problem it should be much more visible.

Comment: `head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));` gives you an uninitialized `head` node

Comment: By the way, `if (head_ref == NULL) { head_ref->next ... }`? If `head_ref` is a null pointer the you dereference that null pointer, which is invalid and leads to *undefined behavior*. I think you might need to take a step back, and concentrate of the basics of list handling first.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two bugs:

**1. Uninitialized `head` node**

Here

```
Node * head = NULL;
head = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

you create a `head` node without initializing it. That can explain why the first tag in your output is "strange".

That said, your program could just as well run into a crash when you later use those uninitialized values.

You probably should not create a `head` node until the first tag is found.

**2. Never compares the tag-name of the last node**

For checking if a tag is already in the list, you do:

```
                while(last->next != NULL)
                {
                    if(strcmp(last->data, tagName) == 0)
                    {
                        found = 1;
                        last->count++;
                    }
                    
                    last = last->next;
                }
```

Due to `while(last->next != NULL)` you will never reach the string compare for the last node. This is the reason that `span` appears twice in your output.

Try with `while(last != NULL)` instead.